# magnific popup: how to add support for youtu.be shortened links

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube, same-origin-policy, magnific-popup

With links like `http://youtu.be/1wAlbzKoYbs` I am getting this error:

```
Refused to display 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wAlbzKoYbs&feature=youtu.be' 
in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

Is there a way to fix that?

Links like `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wAlbzKoYbs` works.

http://jsfiddle.net/6vheh/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easier than I thought:)

```
        iframe: {
            patterns: {
                youtube_short: {
                  index: 'youtu.be/',
                  id: 'youtu.be/',
                  src: '//www.youtube.com/embed/%id%?autoplay=1'
                }
            }
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6vheh/2/

Comment: Can you explain how the addition of these options worked out for you? I'm passing my src from the href in my anchor. My script:
var videoSrc = jQuery('a.play-video').attr('href');
So I'm using most of the same script you did above, src: videoSrc and now get this error:
GET file://www.youtube.com/embed//www.youtube.com/embed/4o2sA0vpA-4 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: @user1380540 Seems you are testing on a local machine, and the two slashes (//youtube...) translate to file://youtube... instead of http://youtube... You might prepend "http" to the SRC string in order to get the video from a local machine.